# How Can I Align 2 Separate Large Spreadsheets in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am trying to align two spreadsheets in Excel 2010, where not all of the information matches. Spreadsheet 1 has approximately 67,000 rows of data, while Spreadsheet 2 has 54,000.

I need to match the information in Spreadsheet 2 (Columns L-P) via the corresponding UPC Number in Spreadsheet 1. (Columns A-J) If I do not have a UPC Match in Spreadsheet 2 for the UPC in Spreadsheet 1, it could stay blank or read 'MISSING'.

So the end result would be a combined spreadsheet with the values from Spreadsheet 2, aligned via UPC, with Spreadsheet 1.

(Pic Attached)
[Excel 2010 Spreadsheet 1 &2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf3PY.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the `vlookup()` function... It's awesome! https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: I'll give that a shot - thank you!